# Strange pop-up search activated by keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, search

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and half an hour ago I manged to accidentally (while trying to CTRL+f find something in Chrome) open a popup search window I've never seen before. I think it had a transparent dark-green coloured background, a search bar and rounded corners. It seemed very out of place with the usual Ubuntu graphic layout. I think the title had something to do with functions. I closed it quickly because I was in the middle of something but it got me really curious. Tried to search various keyword combinations on Google but to no avail. Any idea what it could have been?

Comment: Is that Ubuntu Unity or Gnome? Sounds like Looking Glass... https://archeando.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/fa285-lookingglass.png (the look can change a lot). Just guessing

Comment: @Rmano Ubuntu Unity. It does look similar but I am pretty sure I don't have it installed.